# Why does Project Properties View of Eclipse Jaspersoft Studio plugin sometimes display white text (on white background :-( )?

Tags: eclipse, jasper-plugin

(I think I saw this with other plugins in the past as well)
(Eclipse Neon with Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.2)

[image: project properties with white text]

It could be related to using the project in different workspaces or Eclipse versions (Neon) at the same time?!

Comment: I also already tried to delete the `<myproject>/.settings/com.jaspersoft.studio.prefs` file and compared the newly created to the old without success in seeing a difference or making one.

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: the OS is `Win 7 Enterprise SP1` (64bit)